ggalluvial: Order flow of lines based on a variable so they converge when reaching the next stratum
I'm plotting an alluvial diagram in RStudio wth the below code. My original dataset is in wide format.
I want to plot it in a way that when flows (color defined by the variables in the first axis, "Stakeholder_Type") reach the next stratum, e.g. when "Researchers" who vote "Yes" from German-speaking regions choose "Unsure" in Scientific communication, it should be one single, thicker dark blue line and not 4 thin lines. And same goes for the next strata.
Here's the plot I created with the original data:

Below is the script for the first 10 rows of data and these are sufficient to reproduce the problem described.
I also tried aes.bind=TRUE in gg_alluvium with no success.
library(ggalluvial) 
df <- structure(list(Stakeholder_Type = c("Anglers", "Anglers", "Anglers", 
"Anglers", "Anglers", "Anglers", "Anglers", "Conservationists", 
"Conservationists", "Conservationists"), German_speaking_region = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), 
    Scientific_communication = c("Inadequate", "Adequate", "Unsure", 
    "Unsure", "Unsure", "Inadequate", "Adequate", NA, "Inadequate", 
    "Adequate"), Influence_responsibility = c("Recreation", "Management", 
    "Science", "Recreation", "Management", "Management", "Government", 
    "Advocacy", "Government", "Recreation"), Importance_involvement = c("Recreation", 
    "Government", "Science", "Recreation", "Government", "Science", 
    "Government", "Recreation", "Science", "Recreation")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame") 

fill_colors <- c( "Conservationists" = "#F7FEAEFF", "Anglers" = "#B7E6A5FF", "Government" = "#7CCBA2FF", "Managers" = "#089099FF", "Researchers" = "#00718BFF" ) 

ggplot(df, aes(axis1 = Stakeholder_Type, axis2 = German_speaking_region, axis3 = Scientific_communication, axis4 = Influence_responsibility, axis5 = Importance_involvement)) +
geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Stakeholder_Type), width = 0.25) +
geom_stratum(width = 0.1, fill = "white", color = "black") +
geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), angle = 90, size=3) 
+scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Stakeholder", "German-speaking region", "Scientific Communication", "Influence", "Importance"), expand = c(0.1, 0.05)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = fill_colors) +
theme_minimal() +
theme( axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),  legend.position = "none",  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()

Please help me sort the flows so that those with the same color reach the next stratum (when having the same variable there) converged or adjacent to one another. Thank you and apologies for any lack of clarity as I'm very new to R!
